# Select statement with if statement result

Tags: mysql

i use below command to achieve below algorithm scenario

```
select columnA,
if ((select column from table2 where somecolumn ="A") = "colA")
 as bins from table1
```

Algorithm:

```
select 
 [if value of (select column value = A) == "A"
then select column B
else select column B]
from table1
```

Not sure where I am going wrong in above query. Would someone help me on this !!

Comment: You're looking for CASE; a procedural IF is not valid outside of procedural code (procedures, triggers, events, etc...).

Comment: Looks like in either case (if/else) you are selecting `column B`. Your algorithm needs more work

Comment: Thank you !! I got it !! thank you !! soo much @Uueerdo